# VM sound library

Tags: sound-libraries

Does anyone know the history of the VM sound effects library? May also have named VMX. Seems to be a general all-purpose set of recordings put together in recent decades, guessing 80s-90s?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what this is library (at least by the initials).  What is it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that it's the [Valentino Music](http://www.tvmusic.com/) sfx library. I think it's more popular in the radio world. Definitely discontinued although someone out there owns the copyright.

Comment: @Justin, that's not it. This is not a commercially-released library, but rather that was probably specific to a group of people or facility. Think: Warner Bros, Fox, Soundstorm, Lucasfilm. 

Comment: Can't think of a facility or designer with those initials, so you stumped me...